# import colorama "could not be resolved from source" error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, importerror, colorama

I'm new to python programming and can't find any solutions anywhere. I installed pip and used 'pip install colorama' in cmd, and it worked. No errors. I go into visual studio code, and gives me this error. I'm unsure what to do.

the code vvv

```
import colorama
```

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO9jg.png)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BGuq.png)

I uninstalled it, re-installed it, restarted vs code, I even installed it through the vs code terminal, and that didn't work either. If anybody can give me an answer to my problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check to see if you have the right Python interpreter configured in VSCode. Check [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Comment: This issue is common if you have more than a python source in the computer. You try to check is your pylance python and pip python pointing to the same folder

Comment: Refer [this to select a Python interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter) in VSCode and [this to install packages](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_install-and-use-packages).

Answer (score 0):

- Use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"**.
- Choose the correct python interpreter.
- Open your terminal and use command 'pip install colorama' to install this package.

Answer (score 0):

Use the python interpreter older than 3.10.2.
Colorama doesn't work with newest python.